# Open HTML Embedded in iOS With Relative Background Image

Tags: html, ios, relative-path

I have an app that will occasionally open up HTML pages that are embedded in the app.  What I want to know is how to code the HTML to put the background.

Right now the HTML code I have is:

```
<body background="file:///New Macintosh HD/Users/UserName/Desktop/light-wood-texture.jpg">
```

But again, that is for a local file on my desktop, just need to know how to format it for the iPhone app, as the HTML and image will be embedded in the app itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on where the image is. If it is in the same directory as the code in which you are referencing, I believe you can just do this:

```
<body background="/light-wood-texture.jpg">
```

Comment: I would do that, but I'm having several different HTML files that will load in the same UIWebView, and I want to have a different background for each one.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. Let me know if the snippet I provided works for you.

Comment: Did you make sure that the light-wood-texture.jpg file is in the same directory as the HTML?

Comment: Yes, listed right on top of each other in my navigator, and double checked it is spelled the same in HTML as the filename.

Comment: The navigator can be deceiving. Can you check in finder?

Comment: Here is HTML

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>A Prayer of Thanksgiving</title>
</head>

<body background="light-wood-texture.jpg">
Text of html goes here
</body>
</html>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54231/discussion-between-68cherries-and-user717452).

Comment: Can you try it now? I believe it should work with the /